# How to import bezier curve with start & end mapping property in Unity engine or just bezier animation which is animated with start & end mapping?

Tags: bezier-curves, unity

How to import bezier curve with start & end mapping property in Unity engine or just bezier animation which is animated with start & end mapping?

I tried all available option, but didn't get the result.

[image]